# Excluding Sheet with OnEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm looking to run an automated email script, but exclude two specific tabs, named "Data" and "Carpet". I wrote this to test on just the "Data" tab, but couldn't get it to work.

I have excluded the sheet url and email address for purpose of posting.

Edit - rest of the code works fine, just want to prevent it from running on the specified tabs above

`

```
function autoemail(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  let range = e.range;
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let col = e.range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  let address = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
  let ordernumber = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  let installdate = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  let jobtype = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
  let fieldsuper = sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue();
  let notes = sheet.getRange(row,11).getValue();
  let holdstatus = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue();
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  let url = "MyURL"

    if(col == 11 && sheet != "Data") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'MyEmail',
      address + ' has been updated',
      'This an automated notice that ' + fieldsuper + ' has updated ' + address + ' (' + ordernumber + ') with the notes ' + notes + ', the current status is ' + holdstatus + ' for the install date of ' + installdate + '. For more information, please check the carpet sheet directly at ' + url
    );
  };
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function autoemail(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const excl = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const idx = excl.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (!~idx && e.range.columnStart == 11) {
    const [address, ordernumber, installdate, jobtype, fieldsuper, , , , , , notes, holdstatus] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 12).getValues();
    let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    let cellLocation = e.range.getA1Notation();
    let url = "MyURL"
    MailApp.sendEmail('MyEmail', address + ' has been updated','This an automated notice that ' + fieldsuper + ' has updated ' + address + ' (' + ordernumber + ') with the notes ' + notes + ', the current status is ' + holdstatus + ' for the install date of ' + installdate + '. For more information, please check the carpet sheet directly at ' + url
    );
  };
}
```